# <br> is called while it shouldn't be

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my code of my site. I am trying to echo a `<br>` only when some variable is set. The variable isn't set, still the `<br>` is shown on my website.
this is the code I use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['wwerror'])){
    $wwerror = $_SESSION['wwerror'];
    echo "$wwerror";
    $wwerror = '';
    $_SESSION['wwerror'] = '';
    echo '<br>';
};
```

In 2nd or higher run, why does it keep echoing the `<br>` while I'm using the `isset()`-function?

Comment: in short: read up on `while` loops

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($_SESSION)`. I'll bet `$_SESSION['wwerror']` is set to an empty string.

Comment: What do while-loops have to do with this?

Comment: @Martijn I got the impression the OP wants to break out of the if-statement by using `$_SESSION['wwerror'] = '';`, but then the statement has already been validated, so it's no use.

Comment: Why do people downvote this? It actually is a good question if you start. Setting it to a empty string seems like you unset it, if you dont know that you actually just set it as a string type $var

Comment: @Martijn Maybe because they think that too few effort was put into the question what "set" and "unset" means...

Comment: I have changed the question to counter the arguments for closing, let see if it gets some upvotes and a reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you didnt unset it, but you told it to be [empty string]

```
if(isset($_SESSION['wwerror'])){
    echo $_SESSION['wwerror'];
    unset( $_SESSION['wwerror'] ); // use unset instead of [empty string]
    echo '<br>';
};
```

Small tests for you to see what happends:

```
$example = "123";
echo isset($example) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // Yes, its value is 123

$example = "";
echo isset($example) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // yes, its value is [empty string]

unset($example);
echo isset($example) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // no, it has been unset

$example = NULL;
echo isset($example) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // no, null is special, in php the same as unsetting

$example = false;
echo isset($example) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // yes, false is a boolean (true/false), and saved in the var
```

Comment: Great explanation, +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it might help other people who find this topic :)

Comment: really good! thanks, this helped me out!

Answer (score 3):

A blank string is still considered "set". You need to unset() that variable first:

```
unset($_SESSION['wwerror']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the session variable as a empty string. You should use `unset()` to unset the variable.

```
<?php
    unset($_SESSION['wwerror']);
?>
```